# Advancing Vowel to the Next Vowel in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I'm working on beginner Ruby tutorials. I'm trying to write a method that will advance vowels to the next vowel. 'a' will become 'e', 'e' will become 'i', 'u' will become 'a', etc etc. I've been trying various ideas for quite a while, to no avail.

I think I'm on the right track in that I need to create an array of the vowels, and then use an index to advance them to the next array in the vowel. I just can't seem to create the right method to do so.

I know this isn't workable code, but my outline is along these lines. Where I run into issues is getting my code to recognize each vowel, and advance it to the next vowel:

```
def vowel_adv(str)
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    str = str.split('')
    **str_new = str.map do |letter| 
    if str_new.include?(letter)
        str_new = str_new[+1]
    end**
    # The ** section is what I know I need to find working code with, but keep hitting a wall.
    str_new.join
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your code with the fewest corrections necessary to make it work:

```
def vowel_adv(str)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  str = str.split('')
  str_new = str.map do |char|
    if vowels.include?(char)
      vowels.rotate(1)[vowels.index(char)]
    else
      char
    end
  end
  str_new.join
end
vowel_adv "aeiou"
=> "eioua"
```

Things that I changed include

- addition of a block variable to the `map` block
- returning the thing you're mapping to from the `map` block
- `include?` is called on the `Array`, not on the possible element
- finding the next vowel by looking in the array of vowels, not by incrementing the character, which is what I think you were trying to do.

Here's an improved version:

```
VOWELS = %w(a e i o u)
ROTATED_VOWELS = VOWELS.rotate 1

def vowel_adv(str)
  str.
    chars.
    map do |char|
      index = VOWELS.index char
      if index
        ROTATED_VOWELS[index]
      else
        char
      end
    end.
    join
end
```

- static `Array`s in constants
- nicer array-of-string syntax
- `String#chars` instead of `split`
- use the index to test for inclusion instead of `include?`
- no assignment to parameters, which is a little confusing
- no temporary variables, which some people like and some people don't but I've done here to show that it's possible

And, just because Ruby is fun, here's a different version which copies the string and modifies the copy:

```
VOWELS = %w(a e i o u)
ROTATED_VOWELS = VOWELS.rotate 1

def vowel_adv(str)
  new_str = str.dup
  new_str.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
    index = VOWELS.index char
    if index
      new_str[i] = ROTATED_VOWELS[index]
    end
  end
  new_str
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't come across .rotate yet, just looking it up now in Ruby Doc, it seems to be exactly the method I needed. This executes exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Because we have only a few vowels, I would first define a hash containing vowel keys and vowel values:

```
vowels_hash = {
  'a' => 'e',
  'A' => 'E',
  'e' => 'i',
  'E' => 'I',
  'i' => 'o',
  'I' => 'O',
  'o' => 'u',
  'O' => 'U',
  'u' => 'a',
  'U' => 'A'
}
```

Then I would iterate over the alphabets present in each word / sentence like so:

```
word.split(//).map do |character|
  vowels_hash[character] || character
end.join
```

**Update:**

BTW instead of splitting the word, you could also use `gsub` with regex + hash arguments like so:

```
word.gsub(/[aeiouAEIOU]/, vowels_hash)
```

Or like so if you want to be Mr. / Ms. Fancy Pants:

```
regex = /[#{vowels_hash.keys.join}]/
word.gsub(regex, vowels_hash)
```

Comment: Good job handling capital letters

Comment: thanks @DaveSchweisguth. I imagine we could use the `rotate` method you shared in conjunction with `zip` to generate the `vowels_hash` but it's much clearer to just type it out in this case.

Comment: This is a great solution to include caps. I was just using .downcase and .capitalize, but this has much greater flexibility then what I was doing

Comment: I applaud you for working on the string directly, rather than the "convert-to-array-manipulate-array-convert-back-to-string" dance, and for offering the solution `word.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, vowels_hash)`, but the rest is just a distraction, weakening your answer. The reader will ask, "so, what are you recommending?". Less would be more here. Also, why "Update:"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I came up with the splitting answer first; added the string manipulation method as an edit hence the Update.

Comment: I realize that. What I'm suggesting is that when you submit an answer, then later come up with something better, consider dumping what you had before, as you would if you were writing a book.

Comment: @CarySwoveland People had already upvoted the original implementation; removing it would've rendered their votes meaningless. Plus I try not to modify the code I originally present in case somebody shares the answer link, returns to it later, and finds the code missing. And IMO writing a book is quite different from helping others on StackOverflow. But you're entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

The string class has a [nice method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) for this. Demo:

```
p "Oh, just a test".tr("aeiouAEIOU", "uaeioUAEIO") # => "Ih, jost u tast"
```

Answer (score 0):

To riff of of steenslag's answer a little.

```
VOWELS = %w{a e i o u A E I O U} 
SHIFTED_VOWELS = VOWELS.rotate 1

def vowel_shifter input_string
  input_string.tr!(VOWELS.join, SHIFTED_VOWELS.join)
end
```

and just for fun, consonants:

```
CONSONANTS = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a - VOWELS
SHIFTED_CONSONANTS = CONSONANTS.rotate 1

def consonant_shifter input_string
  input_string.tr!(CONSONANTS.join, SHIFTED_CONSONANTS.join)
end
```